# Sails.js how can I keep track of a users socket ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js

I'm trying to figure out the best method with Sails.js on how to keep track of a users socket id.

I thought the best way would be using `onConnect` in the `config.sockets` but it seems to be deprecated.

Right now I'm setting the socket id in the `Users.socketid` model after they've successfully logged in, but if their socket gets disconnected and automatically reconnects they no longer receive any alerts pointed to their socket like invites or chat messages unless they log out and back in.

So what is the best way to keep a socket id bound to a field in a model? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should clarify you are trying to get the id on the client side right? Here is related question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45431466/1828637